# How do I properly display radio buttons on the screen along with other elements? (images attached) - Java GUI using NetBeans

Tags: java, user-interface, netbeans, radio-button

I am trying to create a pizza ordering system where the user is presented with two choices for pizza sauces (tomato and barbeque). I have already created the GUI and have already coded the design for the radio buttons, but I am not sure how to display the radio buttons on screen along with other elements. I have tried placing it within the paint code and the main aswell, but it changes the colour of the GUI.

I have attached two images. First one is the GUI which is meant to have the radio buttons placed underneath the text (pizza, base&sauce, topping).
Second one is the GUI I get when I add in radio button code.

[image: First one]

[image: Second one]

//Code

```
 package pizzaorder2;

 import javax.swing.*;
 import java.awt.*;
 import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
 import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;

/**
*
* @author sm
*/
 public class PizzaOrder2 extends JFrame { 


static JFrame frame;
static String[] pizza = {"Supremo Supreme", "Supreme", "Chicken",   
"Aussie",
                         "Vegie", "Hawaiian"};
static String[] base = {"Thin and Crispy", "Pan", "Cheese filled     
crust"};
static String[] topping = {"None", "Pepperoni", "Salami", "Ham",
                         "Bacon", "Chicken", "Onion"};

static String tomatoString = "Tomato";
static String barbequeString = "Barbeque";


 @Override

  public void paint(Graphics g) {

    super.paint(g);

    g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
    g.setFont(new Font("Serif", Font.BOLD + Font.ITALIC, 55));
    g.drawString("Pizza Order", 175, 70);

    Image imagepizza = new          ImageIcon("/Users/supriyamayuri/NetBeansProjects/DrawGraphics/src/piz.jpg").getImage();
    g.drawImage(imagepizza, 20, 90, 140, 120, this);

     Image imagesauce = new ImageIcon("/Users/supriyamayuri/NetBeansProjects/DrawGraphics/src/sauce.jpg").getImage();
    g.drawImage(imagesauce, 220, 90, 150, 120, this);

    Image imagetopping = new ImageIcon("/Users/supriyamayuri/NetBeansProjects/DrawGraphics/src/top.jpg").getImage();
    g.drawImage(imagetopping, 430, 90, 140, 120, this);

    g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
    g.setFont(new Font("Helvetica", Font.BOLD, 25));
    g.drawString("Pizza", 40, 240);

    g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
    g.setFont(new Font("Helvetica", Font.BOLD, 25));
    g.drawString("Base & Sauce", 210, 240);

    g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
    g.setFont(new Font("Helvetica", Font.BOLD, 25));
    g.drawString("Topping", 450, 240);



}


     public PizzaOrder2() {

    //Create the radio buttons.
    JRadioButton tomatoButton = new JRadioButton(tomatoString);
    tomatoButton.setMnemonic(KeyEvent.VK_B);
    tomatoButton.setActionCommand(tomatoString);


    JRadioButton barbequeButton = new JRadioButton(barbequeString);
    barbequeButton.setMnemonic(KeyEvent.VK_C);
    barbequeButton.setActionCommand(barbequeString);

    //Group the radio buttons.
    ButtonGroup group = new ButtonGroup();
    group.add(tomatoButton);
    group.add(barbequeButton);

    //Put the radio buttons in a column in a panel.
    JPanel radioPanel = new JPanel();
    radioPanel.add(tomatoButton);
    radioPanel.add(barbequeButton);

   add(radioPanel);


    }



   public static void main(String[] args) {

    JFrame frame = new PizzaOrder2();


    frame.setSize(600, 600);
    frame.getContentPane().setBackground(new Color(40, 80, 120));
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);



    frame.setVisible(true);


    }

    }
```

Comment: how to add RadioButtons? your image shows you have added them. What is your actual question?

Comment: Sorry, what I meant to ask was, how do I properly display the radio buttons on the first image?

Comment: so, if you remove the code to add the radioButtons, you get the first image, do I understand that correct?

Comment: Yep, completely correct. When I add in the code for radioButtons, it gets rid of the background colour I had in the first image

Comment: actually, the background color is still there, but you add the radioPanel over that, and the size of the radioPanel kind of "hides" yours. So, I would recommend to set a size for the radioPanel, and also to set the BackGround color of it. You'll need to put it in the correct location too

Comment: OHH ok, I'll do that. Thanks :)

Comment: I looked online for setting the size and background color but couldn't find proper information that would suit my code. Do you have any idea how I could do that?